# how to show input and select field to one field result

Tags: javascript

this my code

```
Name <input class="has-value m-r" type="text"> 

Gender : 
<select name="post_status" class="form-control parsley-validated" data-required="true">
                                            <option value="">Male</option>
                      <option value="">Female</option>
</select>


Result <input class="has-value m-r" type="text">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okoLxgug/

how to complete this code to show from input field and select field to result alias field and lowercase and -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code should solve your problem.

```js
function changeInput () {
 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
 document.getElementById("result").value = name.split(' ').join('-') + '-' + gender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 Name <input class="has-value m-r" type="text" id="name" onKeyup="changeInput()" > 
  <br><br>
  Gender : 
<select name="post_status" class="form-control parsley-validated" data-required="true" id="gender" onChange="changeInput()">
           <option value="male">Male</option>
                      <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
     
  <br><br><br>
  
  Result <input class="has-value m-r" type="text" id="result">
  
  <br> <br> <br>
  if i input on field name "Jhon Dhoe" and i select Gender field is "Male"
  <br><br>
  on field Result will show alias like this : jhon-dhoe-male (lowercase)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the result you want is for "real time". I mean, every time you edit the name field, the alias field will be updated.

Check this code and tell me if it's what you want.

You should add the aproppiate fields ids, and it should work.

HTML code:

```
Name
<input class="has-value m-r" id="name_input" type="text">
<br>
<br> Gender :
<select name="post_status" class="form-control parsley-validated" id="gender_select" data-required="true">
  <option value="">Male</option>
  <option value="">Female</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<br> Result
<input id="result_input" class="has-value m-r" type="text">
```

JS code:

```
<script>
$("#name_input").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    e = document.getElementById('gender_select');
    gender = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    name = document.getElementById('name_input').value.replace(" ", "-");
    document.getElementById('result_input').value = name + "-" + gender;
})
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okoLxgug/4/

edit: to add jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Unable to get the output which is snake-case of combination of name and gender.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function refresh() {
    $result = $name + "-" + $gender;
    $result = $result.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    document.querySelectorAll('[name="result"]')[0].value = $result;
  }

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    $gender = this.value;
    refresh();
  })

  $("input").keyup(function() {
    $name = document.querySelectorAll('[name="name"]')[0].value;
    refresh();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name <input class="has-value m-r" name="name" type="text">
<br><br> Gender :
<select name="post_status" class="form-control parsley-validated" data-required="true">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>

<br><br><br> Result <input class="has-value m-r" name="result" type="text">

<br> <br> <br> if i input on field name "Jhon Dhoe" and i select Gender field is "Male"
<br><br> on field Result will show alias like this : jhon-dhoe-male (lowercase)
```

External Link: https://jsfiddle.net/okoLxgug/7/